# WCF binding Mismatched

Tags: wcf

My WCF binding is going to be Mismatched. I am using below source .

```
static class Utilities
{
    internal static MessageVersion MessageVersion
    {
        get { return MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10; }
    }
}

public class LiveChatServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public LiveChatServiceHost(params System.Uri[] addresses)
    {
        base.InitializeDescription(typeof(LiveChatService), new UriSchemeKeyedCollection(addresses));
    }

    protected override void InitializeRuntime()
    {
        string pollTimeout = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PollTimeout"];
        string inactivityTimeout = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InactivityTimeout"];

        PollingDuplexBindingElement pdbe = new PollingDuplexBindingElement()
        {
            ServerPollTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse(pollTimeout),
            InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse(inactivityTimeout)
        };

        AddServiceEndpoint
        (
            typeof(ILiveChatService),
            new CustomBinding(pdbe,
                   new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(Utilities.MessageVersion, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8),
                   new HttpTransportBindingElement()),
                   ""
        );

        base.InitializeRuntime();
    }
}
```

If I see the WCF log then getting

> Exception Tree:
>
> > System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel,
> >     Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>
> Exception Information:
>
> Exception Type :   System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089   Message:   Content Type
>   application/soap+msbin1 was sent to a service expecting
>   application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8.  The client and service bindings
>   may be mismatched.   Stack Trace :
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowHttpProtocolException(String
>   message, HttpStatusCode statusCode, String statusDescription) 
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ValidateContentType() 
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception&
>   requestException) 
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.CreateMessage() 
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext
>   context, Action callback) 
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult
>   result) 
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object
>   state) 
>   System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped) 
>   System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32
>   error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped) 
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

`Web.Config`

```
<system.serviceModel> 
   <behaviors> 
      <serviceBehaviors> 
         <behavior name=""> 
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" /> 
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" /> 
         </behavior> 
      </serviceBehaviors> 
   </behaviors> 
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" /> 
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: How can i show config here in Post?

Comment: I am unable to add web.config. further more i dotn have a client side config. i am getting directly using Wcf service View Markup.

Comment: ===Web.Config===
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>